# UIPageViewController transition speed / duration?

Tags: ios5, uipageviewcontroller

Is there any way to change the default duration of the page curl transition?
It is way to fast then I wish it will be?

Thanks
Shani

Comment: here i need to develop the iBook app could you have any idea means kindly help me

Comment: Ugh. Can't believe there is no way to specify this.

Comment: @dineshprasanna yes, there is way a to develop iBook kind app.. please post your question seperately

Comment: @ChitraKhatri thanks for your reply, if there is any sample code means kindly share in this email "dineshprasanna1987@gmail.com"

Comment: Did you find a way ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way to to use default transition to curl the page and to specify the speed of the curl.

```
        CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
        [animation setDelegate:self];
        [animation setDuration:1.0f];
        animation.startProgress = 0.2;
        animation.endProgress   = 1;
        
        if (isGoingBackward) {
            [animation setType:@"pageUnCurl"];
            [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromTop];
        }
        else
        {
            [animation setType:@"pageCurl"];
            [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
        }

        [animation setFillMode: kCAFillModeBackwards];
        [self.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animation"];
```

Comment: Your welcome, if this what you were looking for, kindly accept the answer.

Comment: what is `isFixedLayout` ?! how can connect it to my `self.pageViewController`

Comment: I'm sorry, isFixedLayout is just a boolean related to my code, I edited the code so it would make more sense.

Comment: In order to apply the curl to your pageViewController: [self. pageViewController addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animation"];